# Difference between New/AndNew by New() in Genexus

Tags: genexus

How is the difference between this two news?

```
New
    ProductId = &ProductId
    ProductPriceListDate = &Today
    ProductPriceListPrice = &price
EndNew
```

and

```
&Product = new()
&Product.ProductId = &ProductId
&Product.ProductPriceListDate = &Today
&Product.ProductPriceListPrice = &price
commit
```

Supossing i don't fill this properties, in both way the record will be inserted with null or it will be inserted with empty ('') and 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option is inserting a record directly in the database and null or empty value will be used depending on [Initialize not referenced attritutes](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7946,Initialize%20not%20referenced%20attributes%20property) property.

Second option I think that you're using a [Business Component](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5846,Toc%3ABusiness%20Component,). This case is quite different because is not only inserting a record but triggering transaction rules.
Anyway, in this case "empty" is stored
Note: it seems that you forgot to include save() method in the second option.